relative clauses and adverbs
This is the reason why I like you
A. This is the reason that/which I like you for
B. This is the reason for which I like you

Both A and B are good replacements for "why", correct?

It was the day when I saw her
A. It was a day that/which I saw her on
B. It was a day that/ on which I saw her

Did I also replace "when" correctly in A and B?

I see that when I replace "when" with "that" I can use it with no preposition like in B, correct? It is only possible with "that"  not with "which" and only when replacing "when' not "why"?



All your sentences are awkward.

What's the context? "It was a day that I saw her" seems to require a specific situation (compared to "the day") but I'm not sure what you're going for.

No more context was provided in my book. But it is about formal use

Overall, your changes are possible but clumsy, and not what a native speaker is likely to say.
For example:


This is the reason why I like you
A. This is the reason that/which I like you for
B. This is the reason for which I like you


Now, replacing why with for which is technically valid. But I would go the other way and simplify the sentence:

This is the reason I like you.

Or even simpler:

This is why I like you.


what about A?..

Personally I think it's even worse, which is why I didn't bother commenting. That change has the extra problem of a preposition at the end of the sentence, which some people will criticise you for. Go simple.

I believe my examples are rather formal and then good but for everyday speech they're too sublime, yeah?

@marta No, your examples are awkward. Not smooth, not cool, not good even if grammatical. No one says those things like that.

All of them are akward?

Definitely awkward. @Lambie is right. (Where did you get these examples from?)

Grammar book. Chapters about formality

So if you are quoting directly from that grammar book, I would get a better book. If you are using examples from the book to make your own sentences, you could quote the book sentence and we could help you to use it better.

B is excatly the same as in my book. A is my version
